# Blog post hovers: Not letting the user hover over posts with specific IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have `articles` (blog posts) set up so that the user can hover over them to reveal the titles. However, for articles with a class of `post-0`, I'd like the titles to just be shown without the user needing to hover over them.

After researching jQuery's selectors, it looks like the [.not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector needs to be used, but I am totally confused as to how to implement it into the code. Below is the script I'm using. Can anyone show me a way to achieve this?

So I'd like to implement something like `$( "article" ).not( ".post-0" );`

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dz30ov2a/

Basically, I don't want the 'coming soon' box to be "hoverable".

JavaScript

```
$(document).on("mouseenter mouseleave", "article", function( e ) {

        // mouseenter variable returns true if mouseenter event is occurring 
        // and it returns false if event is anything but mouseenter.
    var mouseenter = e.type === "mouseenter",
        $this = $(this),
        img = $this.children('img'),
        postInfo = $this.children('.post-info');

        // Both of these use ternary if statements that are equal to:
        // if ( mouseenter ) { var imgFade = 0.4; } else { var imgFade = 1; }
        // if ( mouseenter ) { var postInfoFade = 'fadeIn'; } else { var postInfoFade = 'fadeOut'; }
    var imgFade = mouseenter ? 0.4 : 1,
        postInfoFade = mouseenter ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut';

    img.stop().fadeTo( 500, imgFade );
    postInfo.stop()[ postInfoFade ]( 500 );

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="article-list">
    <article id="post-1" class="post-1 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-uncategorized">
        <div class="post-info">
            <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="post-1/" rel="bookmark">Post 1</a></h1>
            <span class="posted-on">
                <a href="post-1/" rel="bookmark">
                    <time class="entry-date published" datetime="2014-08-14T13:02:27+00:00">August 14, 2014</time>
                    <time class="updated" datetime="2014-09-05T02:20:16+00:00">September 5, 2014</time>
                </a>
            </span>
        </div>
        <img width="312" height="200" src="http://i.imgur.com/DYsiQ1a.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="post-1" style="opacity: 0.4;">  
    </article><!-- #post-## -->                             
    <article id="post-0" class="post-0 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry">
        <div class="post-info">
            <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="" rel="bookmark">Coming Soon</a></h1>
            <span class="posted-on">
                <a href="" rel="bookmark">
                    <time class="entry-date published" datetime="2014-08-14T13:02:27+00:00">August 14, 2014</time>
                    <time class="updated" datetime="2014-09-05T02:20:16+00:00">September 5, 2014</time>
                </a>
            </span>
        </div>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8rca7SA.gif" alt="Coming soon" style="opacity: 1;">    
    </article><!-- #post-## -->
</div>
```

Comment: Post your HTML as well. And a fiddle.

Comment: @j08691 Done and done.

Comment: So like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6g1qd4Lb/?

Comment: @j08691 Yes, just like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you should is remove the interaction with Javascript if it is static.

1. add a CSS rule that ".post-0" will visible without need of hover
2. $(document).on("mouseenter mouseleave", "article:not(.post-0)",  function(){....})
3. Write code in self explain way, by adding a new class "static-article" and do "article:not(.static-article)" will make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Changing:

```
$this = $(this),
```

to:

```
$this = $(this).not('.post-0'),
```

seems to fix it.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6g1qd4Lb/)**